# How do I alter my API request based on a field from the user?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What I would like is an API request that gives me data based on a field from the User.

i.e. If the User is premium, give all of the data, otherwise, give a subset of that data.

This is easy enough, as shown in the DRF
[filtering documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/):

```
class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return Purchase.objects.filter(purchaser=user)
```

**The problem:**

I currently have it set up so anyone trying to access the API needs a Token. But, I'd like a 'Guest' user (someone who is not logged in) to still be able to see some data from my API.

I am using these Django Rest Framework settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT": "json",
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the permissions for individual views.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class PurchaseList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PurchaseSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

Then you might want to alter the behaviour in `get_queryset` if the user is not logged in

```
if request.user.is_anonymous:
   # do something different
```

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate the guest user functionality as well, thank you.